# GitHub API: Update user notification settings

Tags: github, github-api

Is it possible to update GitHub user notification settings using the GitHub API?

I am most interested in updating the 'participating' notification settings, in the context of GitHub Enterprise.

[image]

Nothing in the [Users](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.21/v3/users/) or [Notifications](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.21/v3/activity/notifications/) API documentation suggests this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can see is the [Set a repository subscription](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/activity#set-a-repository-subscription), but it applies to a given repository, not to the global user settings for Watching events.

So it appears those specific settings are not exposed through an API call (nothing in the [User API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/users) for instance)

Comment: On set repository subscription, you're setting whether the user should receive a notification; not how they should receive it (email/web).

Comment: @DavidPoxon True. I don't see that exposed through API though.